# Why does my session variable clear after closing the browser?

Tags: python, session, flask

Here is a code snippet that is a simple note application that takes in input from the user and displays the notes on the browser. The notes are stored in the session variable provided by flask. **My question is that even though the server is running and the notes I entered are in the variable, why does the notes variable clear when I close the browser?**

**How can I make it persist even after the browser closes? Please let me know a solution with the use of session variable only.**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, session
from flask_session import Session

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"
Session(app)

print(app.config)
notes = []

@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    if session.get("notes") is None:
        session["notes"]=[]

    if request.method == "POST":
        note = request.form.get("note")
        session["notes"].append(note)

    return render_template("index.html", notes=session["notes"])
```

Comment: *"why does the notes variable clear when I close the browser"* Because closing the browser ends the session.

Comment: Alright, so is there a way to persist that session in flask, without using the cookies explicitly they provide and only using the session variable?

Comment: possible duplicate of [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61972873/flask-session-lost-data/61977128#61977128) explain by @ngShravil.py

Answer (score 0):

Session ID's are generated and stored as a client cookie when the user starts communicating with the server. The sessions themselves are stored in the server (usually in memory, but this is implementation based). 
Sessions are meant to be based on single user interaction with a web page. If you don't set a (sufficiently) long expiry for the cookie, it'll wipe the cookie when the browser is exited. Try setting a `SET-COOKIE` field on the HTTP response timeout.

Comment: What do you mean by "Try setting a SET-COOKIE field on the HTTP response timeout."?

Comment: I'm not a flask expert, but looking at the [documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/documentation) there appears to be a `set_cookie` method on the `response` object provided by flask.

Comment: The link you provided is broken.