# Flask session lost data

Tags: flask

## I am testing a simple app to store data in session. I created the check to avoid resetting, but still getting data lost. Here is my code of app.py:

```
from flask import Flask,render_template,request,session
from flask_session import Session

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = True
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"
Session(app)

@app.route("/",methods=["POST","GET"])
def index():
    if session.get("notes") is None:
        session["notes"] = []
    if request.method == "POST":
        note = request.form.get("note")
        session["notes"].append(note)
    return render_template("notes.html",notes=session["notes"])
```

================================================================

Any time I am posting a new info from form, it gets overwrites the old one. seems session got reset.

Any idea why it happened?

Thanks,
vardan

Comment: Basically, sessions will store only one item per key, so if you update the key, it's previous value will be overwritten.

Comment: But I am appending to a list value of notes key additional note. notes is a key and value of it is a list. So, I can append a new item to that list: session["notes"].append(note).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please consider the following:

1. This is the most **important** point, for flask session to work, you need to configure a `SECRET_KEY`, like below:

```py
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = 'YourSecretKey@123'
```

2. I don't know, I just figured it out that you don't need the following line and it's corresponding import (it started working for me when I commented out this part, may be Flask-Session and Flask's inbuilt session are messing up with each other):

```py
Session(app)
```

```py
from flask_session import Session
```

3. Don't directly update the session, if it's an array, do like below:

```py
note = request.form.get("note")
temp = session['notes']
temp.append(note)
session['notes'] = temp
```

I hope, it will work for you.

Comment: Thanks ngShravil.py, That works for me. But I couldn't understand what really was the reason. And both changes were needed: to remove Session(app) and add SECURE_KEY + add temp to update the session. I am just wondering since in edx course it show that it works that way. Maybe cookie management is different on personal and company laptops?

Comment: I am glad that the answer was helpful for your session issue. I don't think that, cookie management is different on personal and company laptops, it must be same. But a possibility might be there that the companies laptop, block cookies and proxies by default with firewall. But, it goes out of the scope of OP.

Comment: Done. Yes, probably that is firewall blocks cookies. Thanks!